# What is the limited number of requests for OneNote API

Tags: onenote-api

What is the limited number of requests for OneNote API ?

Thanks
Anil Kumar Nayak

Comment: Are you running into throttling? How many requests do you have to make per minute/hour?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the specific limits of the OneNote API aren't public - however there shouldn't be scenarios that aren't feasible with the current limits. You might run into it during development, I recommend simply switching between users for development purposes to avoid throttling.

I strongly recommend reading this blog post for best practices on how to avoid throttling with the OneNote API.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2016/01/12/onenote-api-throttling-and-how-to-avoid-it/